# Number of commits is not being reset

Tags: git, bitbucket

I am working on a feature branch and i notice that my outgoing commits is not being updated.
These are the steps i take:

- i write some awesome code
- i commit the code and the counter of commits is being plussed (to 53 in this case)
- i push the commit(s)
- counter is back to 0 (yeey)
- i fetch the branch and outgoing commits is back to 54 (booo)
- i can verify that the code is actually commited to bitbucket.

This happens in vscode, visual studio (git-plugin) and git extensions

I reproduced the steps in git bash:

```
$ git status
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/Feature/CYPRO-140-BoZ-IV'

$git fetch
* [new branch]        feature/CYPRO-140-BoZ-IV -> origin/feature/CYPRO-140-BoZ-IV
```

I am kinda lost where to look for.
This happens on both my desktop as on my laptop.

Comment: No pictures of code please.

Comment: You have a case sensitiy issue ; do you want to keep branches named `Feature/...` ? or `feature/...` ? (you have to choose, Windows can't manage to have both)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a case sensitivity issue with the name of your branch : you somehow created a local branch named `Feature/...` (with an uppercase `F`), and it interacts weirdly with another branch named `feature/...` (lowercase `f`).

---

The simplest way to fix this would be to fix the remote, then re-clone your project ; if you want to keep your local clone, see the extra instructions afterwards

**fixing the remote**

If you want to get rid of the `Feature/...` branches, and only keep `feature/...` branches :

- inspect your branches, to make sure that each `Feature/xxx` is seconded by a `feature/xxx` branch, and that `feature/xxx` is always ahead of `Feature/xxx`

  - if a `feature/xxx` branch is *behind* a `Feature/xxx` branch, or if a `Feature/yyy` branch exist but `feature/yyy` doesn't exist yet, run :

    ```
    # form your local copy :
    git push origin Feature/xxx:feature/xxx
    ```
- delete all `Feature/xxx` branches

double check on the bitbucket interface that you only have `feature/xxx` branches and no `Feature/xxx` branch.

If you can afford it, delete your local copy, and re-clone a fresh copy of your remote.

---

If you want to keep your local copy, fix the names in several places :

**fixing a local clone** (repeat once for each clone)

- check the name of the directory `.git/refs/remotes/origin/[Ff]eature`
  if this directory has the incorrect `Feature` casing, rename it :

  ```
  cd .git/refs/remotes/origin/
  # that's a plain 'mv', not 'git mv' :
  mv Feature tmpname
  mv tmpname feature
  ```

  *note*: you can also use the explorer to go into the `.git/refs/remotes` directory and rename there, just make sure you fix the name on disk to `feature`
- run `git fetch --prune`
- running `git branch -r`, make sure you only see remote branches named `feature/...`
- check and fix the name of the directory `.git/refs/heads/[Ff]eature`

  ```
  # if needs fixing :
  cd .git/refs/heads/
  mv Feature tmpname
  mv tmpname feature
  ```
- run `git branch`, and check if there are any branches named `Feature/xxx` left
  if there are, check that they are seconded by your `origin/feature/xxx` branches, and delete them
- edit (in a text editor) your `.git/config` file,
  search and replace any instance of `Feature` with `feature`

You should now have a `Feature/` free repository